# If I am now a Australian citizen and I still have a NZ passport

Tags: dual-nationality, australian-citizens

If I am now an Australian citizen and I still have a NZ passport, can I travel on my NZ passport?

Comment: You can use your New Zealand passport if you are a New Zealand citizen, though Australia may want your Australian passport regardless.

Answer (score 8):

**Yes.**  Both [Australia](https://www.border.gov.au/Trav/Citi/Curr/Dual-citizenship) and [New Zealand](https://www.dia.govt.nz/diawebsite.nsf/wpg_URL/Services-Citizenship-Dual-citizenship?OpenDocument) recognise dual citizenship.  Your New Zealand citizenship does not end simply because you have acquired Australian citizenship.

Your New Zealand passport remains valid until its expiry date, on which you can still renew your New Zealand passport.  However, as an Australian citizen, you must now enter Australia using an Australian passport.

Comment: what can happen if an Australian enters Australia by their New Zealand passport?

Comment: @LưuVĩnhPhúc Nothing much special. New Zealand passport holders get to stay indefinitely in Australia

Comment: It is likely that Australia knows you are an Australian citizen even when entering on a New Zealand passport, given the information exchange between the two countries.  It would probably end up something similar to this: http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/22427/i-am-a-dual-australian-british-citizen-with-an-expired-emergency-aussie-passport

Answer (score 4):

Yes, while you are in another country, i.e. not Australia or New Zealand, you are free to choose the passport you want to present.