# Can an Australian re-enter Australia with an expired passport?

Tags: passports, australian-citizens

I am Australian, currently living in Madrid for just over a year now, and I want to return to Australia permanently around mid-September. I just realized my passport expires in late July and the embassy wants to charge me $400 to renew it; I'm almost out of cash as it is. Can I travel back to Australia with a passport that's been expired for 7 weeks?

Comment: You can usually receive an emergency travel certificate for free that is only valid for returning home.

Comment: You are asking two different things here. You can certainly **re-enter** Australia if you magically appear at Immigration there - you're still AU citizen, and you will be let in eventually (with the possibility of fine). However **traveling to Australia** is more difficult - it is unlikely a) the airline would check you in, especially if it is a non-direct flight, and b) EU passport control would let you out with an expired passport.

Comment: @GeorgeY. +1 good answer, you should add it, and I'll upvote. You might also emphasize that airlines are reluctant to board such passengers, even on non-stop flights, because of the hefty potential fines.

Comment: The answer to [this question](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/22427/i-am-a-dual-australian-british-citizen-with-an-expired-emergency-aussie-passport) is also helpful.

Answer (score 5):

You are asking two different things here.

You can certainly **re-enter** Australia if you magically appear at Immigration there - you're still AU citizen, and you will be let in eventually (there is  the possibility of a fine though).

However **traveling** to Australia would be much more difficult:

- It is unlikely that the airline would check you in, especially if it is a non-direct flight - and as Dorothy mentioned above, even with direct flights they are reluctant because there is a possibility of a heavy fine. Note that the airline does not know whether you're still Australian citizen (as maybe you renounced it and didn't surrender your old passport). Also even a direct flight could possibly be diverted to another country due to weather or mechanical failure, and having such a passenger would make things quite complicated for the airline.
- EU passport control is not likely to let you out with an expired passport if they notice it.